# Chrome Extension: getBackgroundPage vs sendMessage. Which method is better?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Question in **chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(...)** and **chrome.runtime.sendMessage(...)**.
The first allows you to get a link to the window background page, the second - to send a message to those who have subscribed to the event.

I feel that the second method is more correct to use, but I don’t have proof of that. On the contrary, I understand that sending messages and receiving a response is a serialization / deserialization of request and response in json, when, when we receive a background page, we get a link to it and it should theoretically be less expensive.

What is the right approach? 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Indeed, exchanging huge data via the direct access to the window object of the background page is much much faster even if you do deep-cloning manually (to help GC do its job). Note there were bugs/limitations in FF last time I checked e.g. in a private/container window you couldn't use the bg page directly. In the end, the major deciding factor in performance-related issues is a performance measurement, which you can do it devtools profiler or manually in the code by using Performance API or Console Timing API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.